# How to export DataFrame to csv without index using rpy2?

Tags: python, r, csv, rpy2

How to remove csv indexing when saving a dataframe using rpy2? Below is how it is done in R, and my attempt python:

R code:

```
write.csv(dataframe, save_path, row.names = FALSE)
```

Python code:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils_package = importr("utils")  # import utils package from R
utils_package.write_csv(dataframe, save_path)  # what to add to remove the row names(i.e., index)?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, `write.csv()` is actually a wrapper for the more general [write.table()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/write.table) function where former has arguments pre-set such as comma separator. Consider using the the more general function in Python specifying the `row_names` -of course still with comma separator. Below includes a few alternatives:

```
# USING WRITE.TABLE()
utils_package.write_table(xmldf, save_path, sep=",", row_names=False)

# INCLUDING NON-DEFAULT ARGUMENTS
utils_package.write_table(x=xmldf, file=save_path, sep=",", row_names=False)

# INCLUDING ALL ARGUMENTS
utils_package.write_table(xmldf, save_path, False, True, ",", "\r", "NA", ".", False)
```

Alternatively, the `ro.r()` object can be used without needing to import base packages:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

output = ro.r['write.table'](x=xmldf, file=save_path, sep=",", row_names=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`row_names=True` work... if the named parameter was explicitly defined in the signature for the function in the R code. Unfortunately it is fetched from the ellipsis `...`.

`**{'row.names': True}` should work.

More in the documentation: http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/robjects_rpackages.html

Note: you also try the dynamically-generated docstring (`?utils_package.write_csv` in ipython).

Comment: utils_package.write_csv(dataframe, save_path, row_names=False) does not work @Igautier. Is this what you meant? I get the error: "unused argument (row_names = FALSE)"